Interpolating the volatility cube of European Swaptions
I'm in a situation where I have a cube of European swaption volatilities (normal volatilities), which contains only scattered data.
Since it is three dimensional (Tenor, Term, Strikes) I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a nice way to interpolate this structure such that I get a "filled" cube, that doesn't contain any holes of data. For example, in two dimensions (e.g. a simple Cap/Floor Volatility surface) for my purposes sometimes it was fine even flat extrapolating on the wings, whereas in this case I fear that a flat extrapolation e.g. in the strike dimension would create weird jumps in the cube.
I'm totally aware of the fact that there are not only much better ways of retreiving a nice cube (e.g. calibrating SABR parameters and retrieving it from those) but also a lot of other issues connected to the approach of directly interpolating on the vols (e.g. creating arbitrage opportunities).
To make my question more obvious:

Do you have any hints for me on how to approach the interpolation of a Swaption Volatility cube with scattered data?
In order to apply simpler types of interpolation I considered slicing the cube. That brought me to the question: In which dimension (Tenor/Term/Strike) do I have which types of consistency? E.g. are Swaptions with the same tenor similar (i.e. 1Y Tenor Volatility will have little movement over the different expiry dates?)

I can specify my question even more, if that's necessary please let me know. My goal is to gain some intuitive insights on the behaviour of the swaption vol in depending on the dimension tenor, term and strike and finally find a pragmatic approach to interpolate the cube.
Thanks a lot!

Not very clear why you don't want to use SABR, as if you have say a few points of 2y1y swaption data you can fit a Skew (may not be the best quality).. same for all other points. Ofcourse in this way you aren't calibrating the surface, but at least getting skews for each expiry and tenor. In any case, I think the most basic things an interpolation algo should solve for in strike space are payer/receiver arbs, butterfly arbs. In fact most of the time, outside of ATMF vols, some strangles and collars, there is little data outside of watching flows go through the market and pricing based on that.

Thanks for your comment. I'm not going against the SABR approach by own choice. I arrived at the arbitrage condition topics reading "A note on sufficient conditions for no arbitrage" (Peter Carr, Dilip Madan) and "Arbitrage-free construction of the swaption cube" (Johnson, Nonas), but to arrive there I would have liked to get a "nice" interpolation approach to actually check on data after I calculated it.
